# Showing that a multiplication operator $M$ is densely defined in $L^2(X,\mu)$ for a positive measure $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space with a positive measure (i.e. $\mu:\mathcal{F}\to[0,\infty]$), take $H = L^2(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and define the multiplication operator $M$ for an arbitrary $\mu$-measurable mapping $f:X\to\mathbb{K}$ by $M_f(\psi)(x)\equiv f(x)\psi(x)$ for those $\psi\in H$ such that $M_f(\psi)\in H$. That is, define $\mathrm{Dom}(M_f)\equiv \{\psi\in H: \int_X|f(x)\psi(x)|^2d\mu(x) < \infty\}$.

I would like to show that $\mathrm{Dom}(M_f)$ is a dense subspace of $H$. I have already managed to show that $\mathrm{Dom}(M_f)$ is a subspace of $H$. However I find the density property to be quite difficult. I am not really sure how you could construct a sequence from the elements of $\mathrm{Dom}(M_f)$ that converge to an arbitrary elements of $H$. So maybe it would be easier to show that $\mathrm{Int}(H\setminus \mathrm{Dom}(M_f)) = \varnothing$?

Some thing to note is that if $f\in H$ then $\mathrm{Dom}(M_f) = H$, although this most likely is not a helpful observation.

What would be a general strategy for density arguments in $L^2$ (or even $L^p$) space(s) that I could apply in this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your field $\Bbb K$ is a subfield of $\Bbb C,$ every $\psi\in H$ is the limit (for the $L^2$-norm) of a sequence $(\psi_n)$ of elements of $\operatorname{Dom}(M_f),$ namely
$$\psi_n:={\bf1}_{|f|^{-1}([0,n])}\psi.$$

Answer (score 3):

For each $N > 0$ let $A_N = \{x \in X: |f(x)| \le N\}$, and $D_N = \{\psi \in H: \psi(x) = 0 \ \text{for}\ x \notin A_N\}$.  Then it's easy to show that $D_N \subset \text{Dom}(M_f)$ and $\bigcup_{N} D_N$ is dense in $H$.